# Royalty Free Videos?

Tags: webvideos, copyright, footage, media

I have seen free images and music, but is there any site out there that gives out free non-copyrighted movie clips that can be used?

I want to be able to search and look for movie or video clips needed to use as examples for my film. For example, if I want a video of a helicopter going across sky I want to be able to find that.

Answer (score 1):

Browse the [Creative Commons repository](https://vimeo.com/creativecommons) on Vimeo for a start. Except for the two non-commercial categories, videos from the other categories can be used for a credit, at most.

> Here’s where you can browse all the videos on Vimeo that have a Creative Commons license applied to them. Creative Commons licenses enable members to grant copyright permissions on their videos so others can copy, distribute, edit, remix, and build upon them while giving credit to the original video’s creator.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the Internet Archive has 2.1 million videos on the [***Moving Image Archive***](https://archive.org/details/movies&tab=collection) catalog.

> <sub>DESCRIPTION</sub>
> **Download or listen to free movies, films, and videos**
> This library contains digital movies uploaded by Archive users which range from classic full-length films, to daily alternative news broadcasts, to cartoons and concerts. Many of these videos are available for free download. Check our FAQ for [more information](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php#Audio).
>
> **Contribute Your Movies and Video**
> Please feel free to upload your movies (Uploaders, please set a Creative Commons license as part of the upload process, so people know what they can do with your movies and video - thanks!)
>
> <sub>RIGHTS</sub>
> **This collection is free and open for everyone to use.**
> Our goal in digitizing these movies and putting them online is to provide easy access to a rich and fascinating core collection of archival films.
> By providing near-unrestricted access to these films, we hope to encourage widespread use of moving images in new contexts by people who might not have used them before.

The Prelinger Archives section is like a gold mine and a wonderful time travel.

Depending on the subject, you'll have to dig a bit, but "helicopter" produces quite a lot of results, like [this one](https://archive.org/details/IMB_SF_R7_C9) that has an AVI with 200MB:

[image: credits] [image: heli image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for examples, for internal work and that won't be displayed publicly, I believe you're not breaking copyright by using images found on youtube, vimeo, etc. At least in my country you wouldn't, but check your legislation.